# iPad App Store Like "Featured Tab" using UIScrollview and UIPageControl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, ipad

i am new to iOS development i am working on an app which is exactly similar like the Featured tab in iPad .

For Example :

App feature Tab in Portrait  mode 
http://postimage.org/image/hpfg55zbh/

Displaying Apps in scrollview

while in Landscape mode

http://postimage.org/image/dpwnbnr4n/

**OHK NOW :** what i am doing is , i am creating a view of size of a cell display in the picture. Lets say if i have 25 Apps so i am creating 25 views and loading image and description of app on that view . When user rotate from portrait mode to landscape i am 
re-creating the views Because i am displaying :

Portrait Mode : 5 Rows X 2 Column on each page .
Landscape Mode : 3 Rows X 3 Column on each page .

Re-creating and Releasing the Views is really not a good practice . Can any one please guide me or suggest me any other technique of doing this ? i have to scrollview and page control thats for sure but i want to get rid of this re-creating method .

**

> Doing the complete development by programming , Not using any NIB

** 
Looking for the best answer :) ... Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that when your view loads you would do the initial creation and when you rotate you would just be repositioning the views by editing their frames. Since you are not using a nib I assume you already have the logic to position the views accordingly.

so maybe you have something like:

```
//Assuming you have these members
UIView *yourContainer_;
NSArray *subViews_;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if(UIUserInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        //create your views and add to container
    }
    else
    ....
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
     if(UIUserInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)
     {
          yourContainer_.frame = CGRectMake(?,?,?,?); //whatever the new size needs to be
          //then loop through all of your sub views to reposition their frames individually within the new container to match the new size and layout
     }
     else
     {
          //the same thing for this orientation
     }

}
```